# ln(5) is irrational - proof verification

Tags: solution-verification, real-numbers

I wonder if my argument is correct.

Any transcendental number to a positive natural number power is irrational.

Proof:
Let $n$ be a non-zero natural number , then $q^n$ (where $q$ is transcendental) is irrational because if $q^n = r$ where $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $q$ would satisfy the polynomial equation with rational coefficients $x^n-r = 0$.

Any transcendental number to a rational power is irrational.

Proof:
Suppose that $q^{\frac{a}{b}} \in \mathbb{Q}$ where $q$ is transcendental and $a,b$ are non-zero natural numbers. Then $(q^{\frac{a}{b}})^b$ is a rational number to a natural number power and so must be rational. However, it also holds that $(q^{\frac{a}{b}})^b = q^a$ and so by previous theorem $(q^{\frac{a}{b}})^b$ must be irrational. That is a contradiction. So $q^{\frac{a}{b}}$ is irrational.

$\ln(5)$ is irrational

Proof:
By definition of natural logarithm, $\ln(5)$ is a number $x$ such that $e^x = 5$. But if $x$ is a non-zero rational number, then $e^x$ is irrational (by previous theorem) and so cannot equal 5. Thus $\ln(5)$ is irrational.

Comment: This is fine.  To rephrase your argument, $\ln 5 =\frac ab\implies e^b=5^a$ so $e$ would be a root of $x^b-5^a=0$, which is impossible since $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: +1 (also) to your question which I regard as both valid and very nicely written.   My sole criticism is that there are several places in your analysis where you use the term "*integer*", where you should be specifying "*positive integer*".  Your argument around polynomials hinges on the fact that a polynomial has terms of the form $ax^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer, except for the rightmost term in the polynomial, of $ax^0$.

Comment: @lulu's method can be used to prove the first part of your argument too: if $q^{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{c}{d}$ with $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$, then $q$ is a root of the polynomial $d^bx^a-c^b=0$, so $q$ is algebraic.

Comment: I am embarassed to admit that I don't quite understand lulu's method. Could you write it with more detail?

Comment: It's really the same as your method, just stripped down a bit.  And I messed up $a,b$ (which might be what is confusing you).  Suppose that $\ln 5$ were rational, we'll derive a contradiction.  Write $\ln 5 = \frac ab$ for $a,b\in \mathbb N$.  Then, by definition $5=e^{a/b}$.  Raising both sides to the $b$ power yields $5^b = e^a$ (note, as I said, that I accidentally switched the roles of $a,b$ in my comment)...

Comment: ...so we have $e^a-5^b=0$.  Now consider the polynomial $p(x)=x^a-5^b$.  Since $5^b\in \mathbb N$ this is a polynomial with rational coefficients.  And $p(e)=0$.  Thus we conclude that $e$ is algebraic, contradicting the fact that $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it.